# parsing email_message['Subject'] results 3 strings instead of 1

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm parsing an email subject and getting multiple strings (depending on the subject length) starting with `=?UTF-8?B?`. Is this normal behavior? How can I join the strings to one string with one encoding?

```
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
print email_message['Subject']
```

...

```
=?UTF-8?B?15bXkNeqINeR15PXmden15Qg15HXodeZ16HXmdeqINeR15vXk9eZINec15TXkdeZ158g?=
 =?UTF-8?B?157Xk9eV16Ig15TXp9eZ15PXldeTINeU15bXlCDXnNeQINei15XXkdeTINeQ150g15DXoNeZINeo15U=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?16nXnSDXlNeo15HXlA==?=
```

**Edit:**

```
subjectDecoded, encoding = decode_header(email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['Subject'])[1])[0]
if encoding==None:
    subjectDecodedParsed = email_message['Subject']
    print 'I am NOT decoding Subject'
    print subjectDecodedParsed
else:
    subjectDecodedParsed = subjectDecoded.decode(encoding)
    print 'I am decoding subject'
    print subjectDecodedParsed.encode('utf8') #<--- Only first line will be presented here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is encoded using the [Quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) format for MIME headers. The [`email.header` module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html) handles this for you, provided your `subject` lines are properly delimited with CRLF (`\r\n`) line separators:

```
>>> subject = '''\
... =?UTF-8?B?15bXkNeqINeR15PXmden15Qg15HXodeZ16HXmdeqINeR15vXk9eZINec15TXkdeZ158g?=\r
...  =?UTF-8?B?157Xk9eV16Ig15TXp9eZ15PXldeTINeU15bXlCDXnNeQINei15XXkdeTINeQ150g15DXoNeZINeo15U=?=\r
...  =?UTF-8?B?16nXnSDXlNeo15HXlA==?='''
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> for part in decode_header(subject):
...     value = unicode(*part)
...     print part
... 
זאת בדיקה בסיסית בכדי להבין מדוע הקידוד הזה לא עובד אם אני רושם הרבה
```

The subject (which is just *one* string with carriage return + newline characters and leading whitespace) spans multiple lines to fit the strict line length limitations set by the MIME standard.